# Python ElementTree - Select a nested xml element based on the value of an attribute

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to select a nested element based on the value of an attribute

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Report>
        <h1>
            <h2>
                <Element name='Bob' age='32' title='President'></Element>
                <Element name='Sue' age='25' title='Vice-President'></Element>
                <Element name='Mary' age='44' title='Secretary'></Element>
            </h2>
        </h1>
    </Report>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

element = root.findall("//*[@title='President']")
```

But I get the following error for the element variable assignment

```
SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element
```

How can I pull the attribute data for the President element only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you're looking for?

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Report>
        <h1>
            <h2>
                <Element name='Bob' age='32' title='President'></Element>
                <Element name='Sue' age='25' title='Vice-President'></Element>
                <Element name='Mary' age='44' title='Secretary'></Element>
            </h2>
        </h1>
    </Report>'''


root = ET.fromstring(xml)
elements = root.findall(".//*[@title='President']")
for i in elements:
    print(i.attrib['name'], i.attrib['age'], i.attrib['title'])
```

Comment: I was missing the dot in the findall and didn't know I needed to loop through elements. Thanks! This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close :-)

The below works - look at the dot in the xpath..

```
xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Report>
        <h1>
            <h2>
                <Element name='Bob' age='32' title='President'></Element>
                <Element name='Sue' age='25' title='Vice-President'></Element>
                <Element name='Mary' age='44' title='Secretary'></Element>
            </h2>
        </h1>
    </Report>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
elements = root.findall(".//*[@title='President']")
print(elements)
```

Comment: Thanks @balderman. I get the element assignment that way, but I can't access the attribute values that way. This does not work: print(element.attrib["name"], element.attrib["age"], element.attrib["title"]). Is there another way to pull those attribute values?

Comment: Did you try and print the `attrib` ?

Comment: I needed to loop through element like @AudioBaton does. Thanks for your help.